# How do I redirect one directory to another using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, redirect, directory

```
/var/
  /www/
    /test/
```

That is my directory structure. I've tried putting various strings in my `.htaccess` (inside /var/www) to try and redirect the visitors to `/test/`, however either I get a 500 error or it keeps trying to visit `http://mysite/testtesttesttesttest ...`

Can anyone tell me the correct string? Here are the ones I've tried.

```
Redirect . test
Redirect ./ test
Redirect ./ /test
Redirect / ./test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to the htaccess file in your document root (`/var/www`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Add a `R` flag to the brackets if you want to redirect the browser instead of internally rewrite on the server: `[R=301,L]` or just `[R,L]` (for 302).